# Could you recommend me game collection books of attacking players?

Tags: theory, books, recommendations

I have found a lack of aggression in my style and I want to study aggressive players' games to develop my style.  Please recommend books that fulfill this purpose. I am an advanced player.

Comment: Not a book, but that [agadmator Chess Channel](https://www.youtube.com/c/AGADMATOR) on YouTube is good. It features a great many attacking games by the likes of Morphy, Tal, Fisher, and Nezhmetdinov. I've learned a lot from watching many of the videos. The ones about Tal and Nezhmetdinov are particularly good, since the person who runs the channel has an infectious love for those two players.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Players to look for (short list, makes a good place to start):

- Mikhail Tal (you can try looking up, say, 'attack like tal' on youtube. eg [1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UxFDzKQkfOA), [2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_u152qz0ZBg))
- Alex Shirov
- Rashid Nezhmetdinov
- Leonid Stein

(Interesting edit, considering it's just video links and the OP specifically requested books, and the links are not even about the named book, which was already mentioned later in this answer.)

Books:

- Rocking The Ramparts - Larry Christiansen
- Storming The Barricades - Larry Christiansen
- The Modern Chess Sacrifice - Leonid Shamkovich
- Attack With Mikhail Tal - Damsky
- Attacking Manual (2 vols) - Jacob Aagaard

From the more recent pile:

- Sacrifice and The Initiative in Chess - Ivan Sokolov

And if more distant historical players are more your thing, look for:

- Alexander Alekhine
- Harry Nelson Pillsbury
- Rudolf Spielmann
- Frank Marshall

Answer (score 6):

I am probably too weak to give advices (I am somewhere between 1700-1800 on chess.com), but since I am on a similar road maybe those books will help:

- *Attacking Chess: Aggressive Strategies and Inside Moves - Josh Waitzkin* - I have read this book entirely. Actually it does not teach you a method, but various cases. It is a fun text to read, and it shows you about the mood and attitude you have to have. The examples are instructve but you have to take your time to absorb them
- *A Guide to Attacking Chess - Garry Lane* - This teaches you elements and can constitute a method to attack. It is really instructive and a really good book
- *Looking for Trouble - Dan Heisman* - This is not about attacking, but more about spotting mistakes. However this is important, since when you have advantage you have to push and when you are on defense you have to solidify. But any mistake can change that, and when a mistake is not spotted than everything changes.
- *How to Reasses Your Chess - Jeremy Silman* - This is not a book about attack. It is about imbalances. But you can attack successfully if you have a reason (weaknesses, space, speed, etc). Otherwise attacking blindly is like trying to destroy a fortress by hitting your head into walls. No chance. Any alternative book about positional elements gives you reasons for attacks.
- (Addition edited in by H.R.) A classic is *Art of Attack in Chess - Vladimir Vukovic*, with special view on attacking the king (uncastled, castled with no weaknesses, castled with weaknesses, with pawns, with officers...).

Comment: Are there any books of a particular player's collection? I think that way I can incorporate aggression into my style better.

Comment: Another recommendation of a classic: "Art of Attack in Chess", Vukovic.

Comment: @HaukeReddmann you should add it as an answer. I starting to inspect that and it looks very interesting, thank you

Comment: @rapaio: I have enough karma and simply edited into your answer, hope you don't mind, just revert if you don't like  :-)

Comment: @HaukeReddmann not at all, it was just an occasion to give a deserved vote as a thank you :)